# SublimeText: plugin to copy variable import declaration?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have this use-case that happens often in my django dev daily life : I want to execute a piece of code taken from my app into [`shell_plus`](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html)

For example this queryset :

```
bookings_sent = Mail.objects.filter(_type=cts_mail.MailId.GIVE_MONEY).filter(
    booking__in=bookings).values_list('booking', flat=True)
```

So I copy the line in `shell_plus` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> but then the shell rightfully yells because of undefined `cts_mail` variable.
I have to find the import at the top of the file and paste it into the shell, then it yells for another constant, yadda yadda yadda...

**Ideally, I'd like to select in ST3 the lines I want to execute in the shell and do a right-click *"Prepend required imports"* so the imports appear right on top of my selection and i can copy the whole block to `shell_plus` in one swoop.**